# Angular 2: ngIf not working inside a child component

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am working on create a component that have two inputs one is a number and one is a text as following:

```
    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="inputType=='text'">
       <input class="form-control"  type="text" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="inputType=='number'">
        <input class="form-control"  type="number">
    </div>
```

and `.ts` file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-elemnt-validation',
  templateUrl: './form-elemnt-validation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-elemnt-validation.component.css']
})
export class FormElemntValidationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  inputType="text";
  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

but `ngIf` not working even if change the condition to true and nothing of two inputs appears!!

please note that this component is used inside another component. which also used inside third component.

ReceivedPaymentsPage
   SubmitPaymentsComponent
     FormElemntValidationComponent

and the .module file declaration:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    SearchModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ReceivedPaymentsPage,
    InvoiceShowDataComponent,
    ReceivedPaymentsTableComponent,
    SubmitPaymentsComponent,
    FormElemntValidationComponent
  ]

})
```

any one knows why `ngIf` not working in this case?

Comment: it is working as expected, the problem might be in some other location? see this link: https://plnkr.co/edit/KSWPYD3mhJgmdYJfwgH5?p=preview

Comment: Have you imported FormsModule in app.component.ts file.

Comment: yes FormsModule is imported in the module that contains the declaration of this component

Comment: @ Faisal , I don't know why it is not works in my case, I think its a trivial issue!

Comment: I edited the question and added some details that may help in understanding the issue

Comment: please create a plunker to reproduce this issue, then we can solve it. Here is a link to template: https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue

Answer (score 0):

This can be done please have look this [Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/sEsz7WIOABLYOxNnaOzZ?p=preview)

**JS**

```
  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <div>
        <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
        <cart></cart>
      </div>
    `,
  })
  export class App {
    name: string;
    constructor() {
      this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
    }
  }

  @Component({
    selector: 'cart',
    template: ` <div class="form-group" *ngIf="inputType=='text'">
         <input class="form-control" placeholder='Text'  type="text" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" *ngIf="inputType=='number'">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder='Number'  type="number">
      </div><button (click)='changeText()'>change</button>`
  })

  export class Cart {
    inputType = 'text'
    construtor() {

    }
    changeText() {
      this.inputType = 'number'
    }
  }
```

This will work

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your issue is related to your component module structure , 
i suggest to delete this component and create it in the same directory with it is parent.